# Working efficiently with Jinja Python templates in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jinja2, syntax-highlighting

How can I leverage the syntax comprehension features of PyCharm when editing Jinja templates of Python code?

If I set the syntax of my `template.py.jinja2` file to Python, I get numerous false positive syntax errors due to Jinja syntax, and and incorrect formatting as PyCharm assumes I'm typing invalid Python code.

Comment: Did you try enabling jinja template from Language & Frameworks -> Python template language?

Comment: @sonus21 I don't have that option under Language & Frameworks (or anywhere else, if I search for "template"). Could this be a version or plugin thing? I'm using PyCharm 2019.2.5.

Comment: It might not available in the community edition. Not sure whether your software is PycharmPro or not.  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ See the comparison section

Answer (score 1):

Yup in a pycharm community edition templating is not available. As workaround you can run `j2cli` in "*Before launch*" section of your project "*Run/Debug Configuration*".

To do this first install `j2cli` into your project environment (*Settings*->*Project* ->*Project Interpreter*). Then create "*Before launch*" task: *Run/Debug Configuration*->*Before launch* click on "+" button then select "*Run External tool*". In "*External tools*" window click on "+" again and then fill "*Create tool*" window fields.

Here [my configuration of "*Create tool*" window fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQNle.png) (for windows 10), which is processed any files with `*.py.j2` extension and use corresponding `*.py.json` file as jinja config:

- **Name**: as you wish
- **Description**: as you wish
- **Program**: `forfiles`
- **Arguments**: `/m *.py.j2 /c "cmd /c $PyInterpreterDirectory$\j2.exe @FILE @FNAME.json -o @FNAME"`
- **Working directory**: `$ProjectFileDir$`
- **Synchronize files after execution**: `{+check}`

For linux "*Create tool*" window fields should look like this (**!NOT TESTED!**):

- **Program**: `find`
- **Arguments**: `. -type f -name '*.py.j2' -exec sh -c '$PyInterpreterDirectory$\j2 $1.$2 $1.json -o $1'`
- **Working directory**: `$ProjectFileDir$`
- **Synchronize files after execution**: `{+check}`